# How can another Firefox extension mark a site as "trusted" in NoScript?

Tags: integration, firefox-addon, noscript

I am looking to write an extension that will integrate with [the Web of Trust API](http://www.mywot.com/en/blog/api-for-firefox-extensions) to mark sites with good reputation as trusted automatically.

However, from what I can understand, there is no easy way to integrate with NoScript.  What I would need to do is check if a site is on the trusted or untrusted list, and add it to the trusted list if it's not already on either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NoScript seems to use *capability.policy.maonoscript.sites* as user preference in order to store the allowed sites (see yourself at *prefs.js* on your firefox profile)... just try reading/inserting in it (hope *"@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"* allow it ;))

P.S.: NoScript uses *chrome://noscript/content/Sites.js* in order to handle these data

Happy Hacking

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most helpful answer.